# Unusual font on some sites (like Facebook)

Tags: 14.04, fonts, chromium, facebook

Some of the fonts on popular web sites (like Facebook) have changed since I reinstalled 14.04 LTS. I'd only originally had it installed for about a week, and the fonts seemed normal. But since reinstalling some of the fonts have changed to something less easily readable.

Old (better) font:

[image]

New (worse) font:

[image]

How do I change the font back, or what might have changed it? I have the Unity Tweak Tool installed and the fonts on their default settings (as they were before reformat). Could it be `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`? Because I'm not sure if that was installed on my last go-around.

Edit: Sorry, completely forgot to mention, the web browser is Chromium in both cases.

Comment: Right click and inspect the element. In the *Computed* tab, look for the `font-family`, and at the bottom, *Rendered Fonts*. Post them both here.

Comment: When I inspect the element, I don't see a *Computed* tab, but in the *Styles* section I can see the line:

    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif

Then further down, there's a line that reads `font-family: 'lucida' ` but this has a line through it.

Comment: Does it look the same in Firefox or is it Chromium issue? Relevant package versions?

Comment: In Firefox, the font is the same, but is much taller and more readable. Looking side-by-side with Chromium, Chromium looks stretched horizontally in comparison.
Note: This is not a zoom issue. Both are at 100% zoom, and other fonts on the page appear identical. Only this particular font appears different between the browsers.

Chromium: Version 48.0.2564.116
Firefox: Version 44.0.2

Comment: font-family lists fonts in the order of precedence. You've mentioned MS Core Fonts package. It may have caused this: when you installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, its fonts become more preferable than sans-serif. Try uninstalling this package, reboot and recheck.

Comment: After completely removing and rebooting, the fonts are back to their original, so it looks like `tts-mscorefonts-installer` was the cause. Do you know if there is a way to install the package without the fonts becoming the preferred option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by performing a complete uninstall of `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and restarting the system, per whtyger's suggestion.

Comment: And now, when we've found the source of the trouble, we can re-install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and try to fix your fonts issue.

Answer (score 4):

Font substitutions for your case are described in the file `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-metric-aliases.conf`. It looks complex at the first glance, but it is pretty logical.
Your "better" font is `Liberation Sans` and it replaced `Helvetica` and `Arial` everywhere, until you installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. Now `Arial` appeared in your system and it is more preferable than `Liberation Sans`, according to the substitution rules (they can be found in the "Map generics to specifics" section of the mentioned file).
You can override these rules with your personal rule file. Create the file with the name `local.conf` somewhere and put the next lines in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

<!-- Map generics to specifics (overrides 30-metric-aliases.conf) -->

    <alias binding="same">
      <family>Helvetica</family>
      <accept>
      <family>Liberation Sans</family>
      </accept>
    </alias>

</fontconfig>
```

Now copy it to the folder with the font settings:

```
sudo cp local.conf /etc/fonts
```

Reboot and check whether your "better" font has replaced the "worse" one.
**NB** This trick replaced only sans-serif font, but it can be used to set the precedence of the serif and monospaced fonts at your desire.